Itextpdf Sign For "Digitally signed by ..."
When I use itextpdf's package to sign PDF, I successfully signed the PDF, but the signature content displayed after signing is "Digitally signed by..." which does not show the name of the signer, but my PDF view The signer was identified in the tool. How do I need to modify my code so that the signer can be displayed in the document?

The following is part of my code. I want to display the signer's information in my signature content. What changes do I need to make?
 static byte[] prepareAndHashForSigning(PdfReader pdfReader, OutputStream outputStream, String fieldName) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfReader, outputStream, (char) 0);
    PdfSignatureAppearance pdfSignatureAppearance = pdfStamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    pdfSignatureAppearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(80, 140, 188, 172), 1, fieldName);
    ExternalSignatureContainer blankContainer = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(pdfSignatureAppearance, blankContainer, 12000);
    InputStream rangeStream = pdfSignatureAppearance.getRangeStream();
    BouncyCastleDigest bouncyCastleDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(rangeStream, bouncyCastleDigest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
    return hash;
}

/**
 * This method sets the signature container placeholder in the signature dictionary
 * value of the signature field with the given name.
 */
static void injectPkcs7Container(PdfReader pdfReader, OutputStream outputStream, String fieldName, byte[] signatureContainer) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    ExternalSignatureContainer injectingContainer = new InjectingSignatureContainer(signatureContainer);
    MakeSignature.signDeferred(pdfReader, fieldName, outputStream, injectingContainer);
}

/**
 * This is a dummy method that returns the given hash itself instead of a signature
 * container for it. Obviously, it is not for production purposes.
 */
static byte[] retrievePkcs7ContainerForHash(byte[] hash) {
    String base64CertificateString =".....";
    byte[] decodedCertificateBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64CertificateString);
    return decodedCertificateBytes;
}

/**
 * This {@link ExternalSignatureContainer} implementation returns a pre-generated
 * byte array in its {@link #sign(InputStream)} method.
 */
static class InjectingSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
    final byte[] signatureContainer;

    public InjectingSignatureContainer(byte[] signatureContainer) {
        this.signatureContainer = signatureContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        return signatureContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File origFile = new File("POL571_RedLight_company.pdf");
    File tempFile = new File("deferredContainerSigningTemp.pdf");
    File resultFile = new File("deferredContainerSigningResult.pdf");
    String fieldName = "Signature";
    byte[] hash = null;
    try (
            OutputStream tempOutput = Files.newOutputStream(tempFile.toPath())
    ) {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(origFile.getPath());
        hash = prepareAndHashForSigning(pdfReader, tempOutput, fieldName);
        String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (DocumentException | GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    byte[] signatureContainer = retrievePkcs7ContainerForHash(hash);

    try (
            OutputStream resultOutput = Files.newOutputStream(resultFile.toPath())
    ) {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempFile.getPath());
        injectPkcs7Container(pdfReader, resultOutput, fieldName, signatureContainer);
    } catch (DocumentException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


The signature appearance is part of the signed content. Thus, it is generated in the preparation step (prepareAndHashForSigning). But in that step your code does not give iText any indication who the signer is. Thus, the automatically created appearance cannot contain the signer name. To include an indication, you can e.g. generate the text yourself and set it as Layer2Text.

oh I understand, when preparing the signature container, I don't have the signature's information yet, so when creating the signature appearance, I can't display the signer information. If I need to define the signer's information before signing, I need to use the setLayer2Text method to customize the signer's information. Is it okay if I understand it this way?@mkl

Yes, using setLayer2Text is one option. Another one, I think, is explicitly setting the signer X509 certificate during preparation (if you have access to it that early).
